# node js, function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

so I have a function (getBagId) that I want to return the bag id, I know its not returning it due to the async nature, but how would i go about fixing it so it returns the bagId, heres the code

```
const getBagId = () => {
    request.get('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/users/me', options, (err, res, data) => {
        bagId = data.bagId

    })
    return bagId
}
```

once again I want the function to return bagId so the value is set to that, also i want to do this only using callbacks, no promises or async await, thanks

Comment: If you want to understand async  behavior in JavaScript, this is a great place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: thanks, i understand it, just wondering how i would go about fixing that

Answer (score 0):

Use [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)

```
const getBagId = async () => {

    const response = await rp({ uri : 'https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/users/me' })

    // Process the `bagId` from the response (JSON / XML / ??? )
    const bagId = // `bagId` from response.

    return bagId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of promises:

```
const getBagId = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        request.get('https://www.off---white.com/en-us/api/users/me', options, (err, res, data) => {
            if(err) return rej(err);
            return res(data.bagId);
        });
    });
}
```

But now your .getBagId() returns a promise, so you'll have to handle it accordingly in your application

Answer (score 0):

`request.get` is an asynchronous function, so `getById` needs to return a promise or to execute asynchronously by using `async/await`. Otherwise you cannot do it unless there is some version of `request.get` method that execute synchronously, which I highly doubt that it exists.